# How to make a MySQL generated table interactive PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have currently have a search form that specifies specific information of the users interest and generates a table with the filtered data.

I want to make this table interactive, specifically by allowing the user to click on the row (entry) of interest and be sent to a page with more detailed information about that entry.

I'm a novice at best and was wondering if anyone knew a way to approach this. I can provide more information if required but my MySQL and PHP search is pretty straightforward: The search locates specific columns in the MySQL table and the data that is filtered provides some - not all - the information in a table that is generated from the query.

Comment: `<a href="get_more_info?foo=bar">data from db</a>`, basically

Comment: Or, `<a href="get_more_info?salad=bar">get seconds</a>` - Tastier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply output a link that goes to a page that loads based on `RowId`, but don't forget security involved with passing an ID around.

```
<?php

foreach($resultset as $row)
    echo "<a href='action.php?rowId={$row['id']}'>View Profile</a>";

?>
```

Then in action.php

```
<?php

$profile = user_load_profile_function( $_REQUEST['rowId'] ); 

// do whatever you want to here.

?>
```

Comment: That'll do it! Thank you.